# Reduce file size of UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I want to keep a UIImage the same viewable size but reduce it's file size. Is there a way to do this?

For example, if the user is saving 10 images taken with the camera, i'd like them to come to a smaller file size while keeping most of the quality and the same width and height of the original image.

Comment: You either have to increase the JPG compression by lowering quality, or you have to reduce the size of the image (how many pixels ... e.g. would screen resolution be sufficient). If you're doing this for a `UIImageView`, the latter seems to make sense to me. The camera shoots many more pixels than the device is capable of showing (without zooming in).

Answer (score 0):

save as jpeg with higher compression
(will reduce quality)

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```